# Changing the -watch clock to 12hr vs 24hr in Gulp.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I currently have my files on `-watch` and in terminal I noticed that the time for each change is set on a 24hr clock. Is there a way I can change this to the normal 12hr clock for better legibility?

**Update:**

In addition to Delapouite's suggestion, your log.js file should read as follows for displaying 12hr time:

```
var time = '['+colors.grey(date(new Date(), 'h:mm:ss'))+']';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the logger used internally by Gulp :

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util/blob/master/lib/log.js

As you can see, the format is currently hard-coded :

```
var time = '['+colors.grey(date(new Date(), 'HH:MM:ss'))+']';
```

Fortunately a customisable implementation is on the way :

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util/issues/33